# How to change Tkinter panedWindow width in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm using tk.PanedWindow object to divide my GUI into two panes. I want to change pane width dynamically. Because I'm planing save pane widths on `ini` file to reload after when program is loaded again.

Tried `self.side_panel.configure(width=200)` and `self.side_panel['width']=200` but those doesn't do any effect. Commands seems to be ignored. There is no error message, and nothing changed too.

Below is the simplified version my GUI code. Notice the `# Adjust Geometry` part.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.filedialog
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


class Window(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        # Define GUI
        self.place_gui_elements()

        # Adjust Geometry
        self.geometry("640x500+500+200")
        self.statusbar['text'] = (
                                    "Window: " 
                                    + self.geometry()
                                    )

        self.side_panel.configure(width=200)
        self.side_panel['width']=200
        self.statusbar['text'] += (
                                    " side_panel.width:" +
                                    str(self.side_panel.winfo_width())
                                    ) 

    def place_gui_elements(self):
        # Define GUI Elements      
        self.pw = ttk.PanedWindow(orient = "horizontal")
        self.main_panel = tk.Frame(self.pw, borderwidth = 1, relief = "sunken")
        self.side_panel = tk.Frame(self.pw, borderwidth = 1, relief = "sunken")
        self.map_canvas = tk.Canvas(borderwidth = 0, highlightthickness = 0,
                                        bg="black")
        self.tile_canvas = tk.Canvas(borderwidth = 0, highlightthickness = 0)
        self.scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(orient = "vertical", borderwidth = 1)
        self.statusbar = tk.Label(self, borderwidth = 1, anchor = 'w',
                                    relief = "sunken")

        # Place Already Defined GUI Elements
        self.statusbar.pack(side = "bottom", fill="x")
        self.pw.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

        self.pw.add(self.main_panel, weight=1)
        self.map_canvas.pack(in_ = self.main_panel, side = "left",
                                fill = "both", expand = True)
        self.pw.add(self.side_panel, weight=0)
        self.tile_canvas.grid(in_ = self.side_panel, row = 1, column=0,
                                sticky="nsew")
        self.scrollbar.grid(in_ = self.side_panel, row = 1, column=1,
                                sticky="ns")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    win = Window()
    win.mainloop()
```

Edited -and further simplified- code after @Bryan Oakley suggestion. Unfortunately still not working.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.filedialog
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


class Window(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        # Define GUI Elements      
        self.pw = ttk.PanedWindow(orient = "horizontal")
        self.main_panel = tk.Frame(self.pw, borderwidth = 1, relief = "sunken")
        self.side_panel = tk.Frame(self.pw, borderwidth = 1, relief = "sunken")

        # Place Already Defined GUI Elements
        self.pw.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        self.pw.add(self.main_panel, weight=1)
        self.pw.add(self.side_panel, weight=0)

        # Adjust Geometry
        self.geometry("640x300+500+200")
        self.pw.sashpos(0, 300)
        self.update()
        print ("sashpos %s" % self.pw.sashpos(0)) 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    win = Window()
    win.mainloop()
```

Comment: It would help if you reduced that code down to the minimum necessary to illustrate the problem. See [mcve]/

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `sashpos` method of the ttk paned window to both get the relative position of the sash (the thing that divides the panes), and to set it. If you pass it just the index of the sash (the first sash is number 0 (zero)) then it will return the location of that sash. If you provide an additional argument, it will set the sash to that position.

For example, to get the position of the first sash you would use:

```
position = self.win.sashpos(0)
```

If you read `position` in from an ini file, you can restore it like this:

```
self.win.sashpos(0, position)
```

---

In the updated code you provided, you should call `update` *before* setting the sash position. I think what's happening is that since the paned window hasn't yet been displayed, it's actual width is 1. When you set the position of the sash, you're setting it outside the bounds of the window so tkinter resets the position to the smallest value less than the width of the window.

Comment: @Bryan_Oakley, I've tried to implement your suggestion but it doesn't work for some strange reason. I add the code to the end of the question.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe too late, but for others, I managed to resize the panes only after a small delay

```
self.after(50, lambda: self.win.sashpos(0, position))
```